# Why do some scientists believe that the zero point radiation of the vacuum is incredibly powerful?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, energy, vacuum, dark-energy, cosmological-constant

I've been doing some research and i read about zero point energy. I've heard that a couple cubic cm of it can boil the earth's oceans. how does this work if the energy is only 2.7 kelvin? and what are the arguments against this?

Comment: No real scientist believes that you can extract the zero-point energy.  The only people claiming this are scammers who are looking to fool people to "invest" in their fictional devices.

Answer (score 2):

2.7 kelvin is the temperature of the [cosmic microwave background radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background), which is made of particles (photons). That isn't related to the zero-point energy.

Quantum field theory predicts that vacuum has energy even without the CMBR or any other particles in it. That's the zero-point energy.

The same theory predicts that it's useless. You can't extract it and use it to boil water, because that would leave the vacuum with less than the minimum energy allowed by the theory.

There is a reason to believe that it doesn't exist: if it exists then it should have a gravitational field, but the measured field is much, much weaker than the theory predicts. That's the [cosmological constant problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_constant_problem).